# Add a PsiElement without adding text to the PsiFile

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin, intellij-platform-psi

I'm trying to add a method (PsiMethod) to a class (PsiClass) so that IDEA shows this method when typing. I did this, but I ran into a problem: when I add PsiMethod to PsiClass, the text of this method appears in the file, and I don't need it. I need to add a method so that it is highlighted by IDEA, but it is not displayed in the file as text.

**How can this be done?**

Here is my code how I add PsiMethod to PsiClass:

```
val module = ModuleManager.getInstance(project).modules.first()
val file = FilenameIndex
        .getFilesByName(
            project, 
            "TestPsiFile.java",
            module.moduleContentScope)
        .first()
val newMethod = PsiElementFactory.getInstance(project).createMethod("testMethod", PsiType.VOID)

WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(project) {
        file.children
            .filter { it.elementType == JavaElementType.CLASS }
            .map { it.add(newMethod) }
}
```

*Link to this question in the Jetbrains Community:* [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4403743469842-Add-a-psielement-without-adding-text-to-the-PsiFile)

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development so that the IntelliJ platform team could take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you, I did it!